# Sensenet: Search by Content List fields on Query Builder

Tags: sensenet

I'm trying to make an query on Query builder. This query should search by content using the Content List fields.
In the [documentation](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Query_Builder#Query_Editor) is indicated that I can use [CQL](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Content_Query_syntax#Content_List_fields) but it seems that in this case is not working.

The query that I'm trying to make is:

```
TypeIs:File AND #Location:Lisbon
```

Comment: Is this Location field a simple shorttext? If not, can you please try this with a temporary test shorttext field? Because I've just tried the syntax above with a smartfolder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The # char should be url encoded (because the query will be executed by an ajax request through OData). So use it this way:

```
TypeIs:File AND %23Location:Lisbon
```